# Show Header and expand childs

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, expandablerecyclerview

I want to create an expandable view with a header and child, whats the best approach to do something like this:

1. A view to represent a header, that should be the first item of my list

[image: Header]

2. When the header is clicked, it shows the rest of the items. Including itself.

[image: Items]

I dont know if I should use a RecyclerView or an ExpandableList. Can you give some advices or examples to implement this?

Comment: check this out https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view

Comment: I suggest to use Spinner to achieve this.